# Change Category URL in WordPress Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, categories, dashboard

all.
I'm new member and this is the first time I use StackOverFlow.
I consider this is my introduction page for any great coders in SOF.

I would like ask a simple question.
WordPress has very useful interface to edit Category and Tag. What we are going to discuss in this page is 'WordPress Dashboard Category Editor' in "wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category"
Kindly look at the picture below
*Edit: I have no authority to use image, Please look it here*
i.stack.imgur.com/eJ0dl.jpg

look at the "Yucaipa University" above. There are four Menu:

1. **Edit**
2. **Quick Edit**
3. **Delete**
4. **View**

"Yucaipa University" exactly has same link with "Edit" menu above (number 1)
If I click it, it will open the **category editor for "Yucaipa University"**.

What I really wish is:
"Yucaipa University" should has link as "View" (number 4).
Which will open the real category like as **www dot university dot Com/category/yucaipa-university**

I was thinking it is better to show the category permalink when clicking it in Dashboard. If i really want to edit it, I'll just use the "**Edit**' menu. Off course I understand the majority of wordpress user maybe not agree with me. That is why I'm trying to change it only for me and not ask the request to the WordPress developer.

I have tried to find the clue on **edit-tags.php** but still got no clue on how to modify it.
Kindly guide me to get the desired result.

**Arick**.

Comment: Image available at http://s11.postimg.org/cakp7r8wj/Snap_2013_06_12_at_21_25_51.jpg or http://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ0dl.jpg